# Facebook page plugin not showing properly on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, plugins

I was trying to embed a facebook fanpage element into my website.
I went [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) to get a properly working code.
As result I have copied and pasted this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Right after the body tag (as I was told to do)
and this:

```
     <div id="facebookPage">
     <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/StonedMeadowOfDoom?fref=ts"
 data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false"
     data-show-posts="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/StonedMeadowOfDoom?fref=ts">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/StonedMeadowOfDoom?fref=ts">
    Stoned Meadow Of Doom</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

In the footer, where I wanted the box to be. It was inside a block div, but later test proved same effect on all other places.

The problem is that when I wanted to test the thing out, it did not display properly.
The only thing I got was a underlined text "Stoned Meadow of Doom" with a link to the fanpage. No box, no like, no nothing.

So my question is: What did I do wrong, and how can I fix this issue?

inb4. The same effect happened with the script being in the bottom of the , and same effect for the website being on-line and off-line.

Would be grateful for any help

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134145/1956964

Answer (score 4):

Use the IFrame instead of the Javascript SDK. I had the same issue and that worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you testing locally? You'll need to have a server set up in order to see it.

Comment: If you have Python installed, the best way would be to navigate to the directory your website is in and type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and then enter 0.0.0.0:8000 in your web browser to demo the page

Comment: A kinda crazy question..would putting it on dropbox public folder, and launching it from the elements adres do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

if testing locally, try changing

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

to

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

no guarantees though

Comment: yeah, doesn't work locally (i.e. file:///) - you have to have it on a http/s page